# Is 見物{みもの} derogatory?

Tags: words, nuances, politeness

To say something is a 見物, does it have a derogatory nuance like we are making fun of that person / that thing?

If so, is it derogatory to the extent that even if I intended it as a fun joke it seems a bit too much, or is it just *a bit* derogatory and fine to use in informal situations?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It can be. The most common usage of this term is as follows:

```
A) Hey, I'm going skiing with Jack, together with his brand new girlfriend.
    今度ジャックと、ジャックの新カノとスキーに行くんだよ。
B) Why? He has never been skiing and he sucks at sport.
    なんでスキーなの？あいつスキーやったことないし運動おんちじゃん。
A) Yeah! It will be a 見物! hahaha
    だから見物なんじゃんｗ
```

When you say 見物, it implies that you are looking forward and will enjoy seeing how he/she will fail. So you risk to be seen as an asshole. If you are really close with the conversation partner and you fully understand the nuance of this term, you could use it to joke, but my advice is to stay away unless you are really confident.

Usage of 見物 as simply something worth seeing is rather archaic now and is not commonly used.

Comment: Enno: nice explanation, but just a small niggling: I think it would be even nicer if you could make your example sentences entirely in Japanese (it gives a better idea of how the word is used and makes more sense than a mix, I think). It seems that you are a native (Japanese) speaker, so I am assuming it would be no problem to you (sorry if I'm wrong)...

Comment: @Dave yep :) Added Japanese example sentence...

Comment: hey thx for the examples too

Comment: I think that 新彼女 is a strange way to refer to 新しい彼女 (new girlfriend) unless the prefix 新- became much more productive than before while I was abroad.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Admittedly it's not very common. But IMO you do hear "新カノ" time to time.

Comment: 新カノ is usual (as a slang).  I have never heard 新彼女.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Yeah I guess it's much better as an example. Changed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's derogatory per se. My dictionary defines it as "a sight/attraction/something worth seeing".

But if used sarcastically I guess it would be.

For everything in general, it's not just what you say, but how you say it.